# PostgreSQL Composite Primary Key and Serial increment?

Tags: sql, database, postgresql, postgresql-9.1

I'm trying to create a table as follows:

```
CREATE TABLE SCHEDULE (
 SESSIONID                  SERIAL,
 MODULECODE                 VARCHAR(10),
 CONSTRAINT SCHEDULE_FOREIGN_KEY FOREIGN KEY (MODULECODE) REFERENCES MODULES (MODULECODE),
 CONSTRAINT SCHEDULE_PRIMARY_KEY PRIMARY KEY (SESSIONID, MODULECODE));
```

The idea being that `SESSION ID` would auto increment with each new row but only local to `MODULECODE`, for example:

```
----------------------
|SESSIONID|MODULECODE|
|---------|----------|
|    1    |    A     |
|    2    |    A     |
|    3    |    A     |
|    1    |    B     |
|    2    |    B     |
|    1    |    C     |
|    2    |    C     |
|--------------------|
```

I believe this is how `AUTO_INCREMENT` functions in MySQL but I suspect PostgreSQL doesn't work this way. How else would I achieve this in PostgreSQL?

Comment: MySQL's auto-increment doesn't work like that, and neither does Postgres' `serial` type. It would be a lot easier if you generate those numbers when _displaying_ the data e.g. using `row_number()` and just keep the `sessionid` as an overall unique value.

Comment: I should add that session ID is not meant to be a unique value. It's unique only to the module, so that a module may have any number of sessions that can be differentiated between. Is there a way I can achieve this?

Comment: You could maybe do something with a BEFORE INSERT trigger...?

Comment: IMSoP, I'm pretty new to SQL I'll admit. I understand how triggers work but I'm not sure where I'd start in constructing one to achieve the functionality above? Any ideas would be awesome :)

Comment: @IMSoP the problem is will also need after update/delete triggers, and things can become messy.

Comment: Point taken thanks. Triggers != good idea

Comment: I understand that the sessionID is not meant to be globally unique, but the "module" unique ID _can_ be generated "on the fly" if you need that.

Answer (score 2):

Show the data as suggested by @Juan

```
select
    row_number() over (
        partition by modulecode order by modulecode
    ) as sessionid, 
    modulecode
from schedule
```

Then when the user asks for a certain sessionid from a certain module do:

```
select *
from schedule
where sessionid = (
    select sessionid
    from (
        select
            sessionid,
            row_number() over (order by sessionid) as module_sessionid
        from schedule
        where modulecode = 'B'
    ) s
    where module_sessionid = 2
)
```

Answer (score 1):

as hourse said you cant do it on your db. But you can asign those values in the select

```
 SELECT row_number() over (partition by MODULECODE order by MODULECODE) as SESSIONID, 
        MODULECODE
 FROM YourTable
```

Comment: Ah, I see. That gives me the data in the format I want, however, I want another table where a Student is able to select a particular `SessionID` for each module in the format that this gives. At the moment, `SessionID` is a unique index in the db which means that students aren't able to pick session 1 or 2 for module B and instead have to pick  session 4 or 5. Any thoughts?

Comment: Sorry @Jamie4840, you lost me. Maybe if you update your question with some sample? For start what if you put this select on a table function? and use it instead of real table? But if that doesnt work for you I recommend you create a new question with the whole problem