# Serial id for every value in a column

Tags: sql, postgresql, auto-increment

I have two tables, one acts as a shopping cart where each row references a user. The other is for the items in the shopping carts, with a foreign key referencing a cart id.
I'm trying to figure out the best way to make serial id's for each item in each individual cart.

Right now I'm ordering the products by their item id and then just getting the item at the correct index in the resulting array, but that's incredibly inefficient since I have to get the entire item table just to get a single item.

This is what my tables currently look like:

```
CREATE TABLE carts (
  id SERIAL PRIMARY KEY,
  userId INT NOT NULL REFERENCES users(id),
  isOrder BOOLEAN DEFAULT FALSE,
  created TIMESTAMP WITH TIME ZONE NOT NULL 
    DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP
);

CREATE TABLE items (
  id SERIAL PRIMARY KEY,
  cartId INTEGER NOT NULL REFERENCES carts(id),
  product INTEGER NOT NULL REFERENCES products(id),
  quantity INTEGER DEFAULT 1
);
```

What I would want the item table to look like is something like this:

```
 id | cartid | product | quantity 
----+--------+---------+----------
  1 |      1 |       3 |      450
  2 |      1 |       5 |       45
  3 |      1 |       1 |       45
  4 |      1 |       9 |       45
  1 |      2 |       4 |       45
  2 |      2 |       4 |       45
  3 |      2 |       5 |       45
  4 |      2 |       8 |       45
```

So I want to be able to get, say the fifth item added to cart number 2 like so:

```
SELECT * FROM items
WHERE id = 5 AND cartId = 2
```

Rather than what I'm doing right now:

```
SELECT * FROM items
WHERE cartId = 2
ORDER BY id
```

And the in the Javascript array this gets passed into:

```
Const item = result.rows[4]
```

Is there any way to set up the tables to do this?

Comment: Except that `id` is unique in your `items` table (primary key), is it not exactly what you have created? Besides, can you add to your question what you want to order records for? Also, we would need to understand how `id` is supposed to be filled (e.g. I do not understand why you're showing 1 - 1 - 2 - 4 for `cartid = 2`)

Comment: Yes, I know id is unique right now. My plan would be to make id and cartId the primary key, rather then just the id like it is right now. Basicly I want id to count the number of items that have been inserted under a specific cartId. It should not have been `1-1-2-4` , it should be `1-2-3-4`, sorry about the confusion.

Comment: this seems to complicate things ,even with using composite primary keys . You might need to use triggers to generate the id value, as serial wont work as you need .

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34074502/postgresql-composite-primary-key-and-serial-increment

Comment: Thank you, that looks exactly like what I'm looking for!